# Правильное расположение файлов sitemap в корне или можно в папке?

Tags: веб-программирование, xml, sitemap

Генерирую сайтмап как всюду написано сайтмапиндекс и в нем ссылочки на хмл файлы, их около 6000 (файлов). По всюду в интернете пишут что они должны быть в корне сайта, но получается бардак. Может ли в корне быть только индекс сайтмапов?

Answer (score 0):

По идее, разницы нет, где у вас расположен `sitemap`. Главное, что бы поисковики "знали" о нем.
А узнать они могут через файл `robots.txt`, или же через вебмастерскую.

Comment: спасибо, я тоже такого мнения, просто хочется порядка в корне сайта)), поэтому собираю мнения как это может повлиять на скорость и функциональность